# What is the correct set up for Google Analytics Multiple domain tracking?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up multiple domain tracking with GA, with the end result being that we are able to see traffic to siteB as containing the initial referrer to siteA.

Site A's code:

```
_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-XXX-X"]);
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "sitea.com"]);
_gaq.push(["_setAllowLinker", true]);
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
```

With a link:

```
<a href="http://www.siteb.com" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link',this.href]); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sitea.com']); return false;">Link to site b</a>
```

Site B's code:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'sitea.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Expected behavior: we want to see referrals in the tracking to siteb linked from the link on sitea as the original referrer to sitea:

```
referrer to sitea -> link -> siteb
```

in analytics as:

```
referrer to sitea -> siteb
```

Actual behavior: we're seeing traffic on siteb as containing sitea as the referrer. Additionally, we're seeing the _utma with the cookie added to the siteb url when you click  on the link on sitea, but the _utma cookies being created on siteb contain different values.

I've read various articles about setDomainName to 'none', removing it all together, but nothing seems to be working as expected.

Thanks for any help

UPDATE: Additional info via the ga debugger:

Coming into sitea from external:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[sitea.com]":  dc_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_setAllowLinker" for args: "[true]":  dc_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":
Referring URL            : http://www.external.com/
Hit ID                   : 1460027114
Visitor ID               : 1908962602
```

Click through from sitea to siteb:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAllowLinker" for args: "[true]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_addIgnoredRef" for args: "[sitea.com]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":
Referring URL            : http://www.sitea.com/
Hit ID                   : 73647255
Visitor ID               : 1908962602
```

So the visitor ID is staying consistent, but the referring URL tracked on siteb is not the referrer from sitea.

Also unclear if it's relevant, but we're using the DoubleClick integration on sitea (dc.js) and Classic GA on siteb (ga.js).

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with **setting the cookie domain (again) in  tag, could you try removing it?**

I suggest to keep it ONLY with all other commands in tracker definition block?

Also, add domain definition to SiteB:

```
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "siteb.com"]);
```

Ignoring referral shouldn't be an issue as you pass UTM parameters that will override that information anyway.

Check out how to set up *Views* (formerly *Profiles*) in GA correctly and [according to documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#keyComponents).

Hope this helps.